# Plot two dataframes with manual legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I'd like to plot two vectors with a legend as well. 
Df 1 looks like this

```
> df1
      df1
1  0.03789634
2  0.24012665
3  0.33449574
4  0.28389631
5  0.27714124
6  0.27867639
7  0.35170168
8  0.32454339
9  0.20677891
10 0.34182049
```

Df 2 looks like this:

```
> df2
          df2
1      0.07975460
2      0.08639309
3      0.07079646
4      0.08163265
5      0.08139535
6      0.10379747
7      0.09550562
8      0.07961783
9      0.09225092
10     0.09090909
```

I can do the following and plot them together but I think it's an overkill plus I find it insanely difficult to add a legend. Is there an easier way to somehow bind them together with levels and use ggplot in a more elegant way?

```
df <- bind_cols(df1, df2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(visits), fill=df) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,10), breaks=1:10)
p + geom_line(aes(y=df1), colour="blue") + geom_line(aes(y=df2), colour="red") +
ggtitle('Df1 versus Df2') +
  ylab('Values') + xlab('Visits') + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse) # for ggplot and dplyr-stuff

library(data.table) # for fread and melt

df1 <- fread('no  df1
1  0.03789634
2  0.24012665
3  0.33449574
4  0.28389631
5  0.27714124
6  0.27867639
7  0.35170168
8  0.32454339
9  0.20677891
10 0.34182049')

df2 <- fread('no df2
1      0.07975460
2      0.08639309
3      0.07079646
4      0.08163265
5      0.08139535
6      0.10379747
7      0.09550562
8      0.07961783
9      0.09225092
10     0.09090909')

right_join(df1, df2) %>% melt(id.vars = 'no') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = no,y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle('Df1 versus Df2') +
  ylab('Values') + xlab('Visits') + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

Comment: yes, but I still believe there is a less complicated solution. Especially for the fread() part. : in case I need to dynamically read these tables for example

Comment: the `fread()`-part is only there for reading in the data you shared in your post. You could use the same function to read in a `.csv`-file for example. And the part that does actually do what you asked for is the `right_join(df1, df2) %>% melt(id.vars = 'no') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = no,y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()`-part, the rest is purely aesthetical.